# Changing values of same Tags without 'id=' and 'class=' and different values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change the values of x, y, width, height. But for each row with different values.

I don't have access to the source code to set id or class. How can I manipulate the values with css, jquery or js? Any ideas?

```
<rect x="0" y="0" width="36" height="3"></rect>
<rect x="17" y="8" width="19" height="3"></rect>
<rect x="0" y="16" width="36" height="3"></rect>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: have you tried anything from your end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attribute selector, eg

```
$("rect[x=0][y=0]")
```

See https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/ for more information

Here's an example:

```js
$("div[data-x]").css("color", "red")
$("div[data-x=0]").css("font-style", "italic")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-x="0" data-y="0">div 0x0</div>
<div data-x="100" data-y="100">div 100x100</div>
```

Comment: It's highly recommended to use `.prop()` instead.

Comment: @JensIngels depends on the property/attribute/data - it's just an example of how to use attribute selector - hardly worth a downvote.

Comment: @JensIngels can you provide a source/citation for your wildly inaccurate statement that it's "highly recommended" to use prop please?

Comment: was downvoted for the exact same thing in the exact same context about a year ago. Just following the community guidelines... In context of jquery you should always use prop over attr. Our university actually repeated this exact statement a week ago.

Answer (score -1):

working example:
In this example I have multiplied every `attribute` for `4`

```js
function changeFunc(){
var elementsLength = $('div').length;
console.log(elementsLength);
for(var index = 1; index <= elementsLength; index++){
      var nthRect = $('div:nth-of-type('+index+')');
      nthRect.attr('width',nthRect.attr('width') * 4);
      nthRect.attr('height',nthRect.attr('height') * 4);
      nthRect.attr('x',nthRect.attr('x') * 4);
      nthRect.attr('y',nthRect.attr('y') * 4);
      nthRect.css("width",nthRect.attr("width"));
      nthRect.css("height",nthRect.attr("height"));
      

    }
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
  var elementsLength = $('div').length;
    for(var index = 1; index <= elementsLength; index++){
      var nthRect = $('div:nth-of-type('+index+')');
      nthRect.css("width",nthRect.attr("width"));
      nthRect.css("height",nthRect.attr("height"));
    }
    setTimeout(changeFunc,1000)
    

});
```

```css
div{
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div x="0" y="0" width="36" height="3"></div>
    <div x="17" y="8" width="19" height="3"></div>
    <div x="0" y="16" width="36" height="3"></div>
```